# Licensing a Jekyll Blog Site, Using Separate Licenses for Code and Content

Tags: licensing

I am working on a [blog project](https://github.com/tohuw/tohuw.net), powered by [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com). I'm having trouble figuring out how to phrase the licensing text, or indeed how to correctly license it all.

Most of the tools, including Jekyll itself are Ruby gems, so that part is pretty clear: those gems are under whatever license they're under. I have a Gemfile calling those dependencies.

Likewise, there are files in the repository (like some of those under `_plugins`) have licenses in the comments. Those are pretty clear, too.

The above two cases I've got numerous examples to work from as far as licensing. Now we get to the other stuff: the code (Ruby, JavaScript, SCSS, etc.), and the content (posts and pages).

I'd like to present the license like this:

- Everything I wrote that isn't content is under MIT, except of course the two cases mentioned above. (Specifically, "not content" can be delineated as not existing in the "_posts", "_pages", or "images" directories.)
- Everything I wrote that is content is under [CC-BY-NC-SA 4.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/4.0/).

How do I correctly phrase this? I thought about making submodules of the aforementioned directories, but that's a bit of a chore.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not a lawyer... but I opted to use this dual-licensing model for my GitHub Pages repo. I was faced with the same dilemma after forking a Jekyll template project. This is what I went with for my [LICENSE](https://github.com/mattvukas/mattvukas.github.io/blob/e7184e99a28f7c29b039f1a3ef042639a9703c1f/LICENSE) file:

```
Blog content license (for all content added since project was forked from barryclark/jekyll-now):
=================================================================================================
Copyright Matt Vukas © 2016, All Rights Reserved


Original template (barryclark/jekyll-now) license:
==================================================
The MIT License (MIT)

Copyright (c) 2015 Barry Clark

Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person...
```

I think this describes the licensing of content clearly enough from a programmer's point of view. I'm not sure if this is an optimal solution, so I would definitely be open to alternative approaches.